# How to check that a INTERVAL is relative or absolute in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, boolean, intervals, date-arithmetic

I found `Postgre` having a very convenient `TIMESTAMP` and `INTERVAL` arithmetic. But the magic also contains some trickery that I would detect when performing queries.

The question is:

> Is there a way to determine if an `INTERVAL` is *relative* or *absolute* in
>   `Postgre`?

Let say I have a column with various `INTERVAL`s in it, some are encoded as *relative* (`'1 mon'`) others are encoded as *absolute* (`'30 days'`).

Because relative `INTERVAL` must be convertible into absolute `INTERVAL`, we cannot compare them directly:

```
SELECT '1 mon'::INTERVAL = '30 days'::INTERVAL;
```

Returns `TRUE`, so we are not able to discriminate.

Relative `INTERVAL`s arise for granulities that are above the week, because week is the largest granulity that is well defined. But such test is not satisfactory:

```
SELECT some_interval > '1 week';
```

Because it falsy detect `'21 days'::INTERVAL` as *relative* instead of *absolute*.

I know that one difference between relative and absolute `INTERVAL` is that the arithmetic returns different results when using them with `TIMESTAMP`.

```
SELECT '2000-02-01'::TIMESTAMP + '1 mon'::INTERVAL; 
SELECT '2000-02-01'::TIMESTAMP + '30 days'::INTERVAL;
```

The first returns `'2000-03-01'::TIMESTAMP` and the latter returns `'2000-03-02'::TIMESTAMP`, which are obviously different.

But this looks somewhat odd to check relativeness by generating some combinations of arithmetic (we can miss some use cases) and it will fail to discriminate between `'1 week'::INTERVAL` and `'7 days'::INTERVAL` (but we can assume it is fine, because they really are equals).

So, I am looking for a *built-in* or *home-made* `FUNCTION` that is able to detect if an `INTERVAL` is *absolute* or *relative* in `Postgre`. Any idea?

Comment: What is the purpose of the distinction?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto, What do you mean?

Comment: I mean why do you need to make a distinction between relative and absolute?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto, Because I need to know if I can rely on the INTERVAL as an exact granulity or if must first convert it into an exact amount of day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call "relative" are timestamps that contain "mon" or "year" (because all month doesn't have same number of days and same thing for years)
you can test it by string comparaison :

```
 SELECT
     my_interval
    ,my_interval::TEXT SIMILAR TO '%(mon|year)%' AS mytest
 FROM my_table
```

Comment: I am not keen to use string casting when solving problem with higher types, but I agree that in this case this must be the cleanest way to do it. Thank you for pointing this out.